# How create table with all days of year using a start_date variable?

Tags: bash, hive, hiveql

I'd like to create a table with all the days of a year using HQL.
I already tried this approach :

[generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

but the hql is a bit different from sql
What's the best approach? 
Using the PL/HQL or using bash script and importing ?

Expected result:

```
start_date = 2017-02-14;

| date     |
|2017-02-14|
|2017-02-13|
|2017-02-12|
|2017-02-11|
|2017-02-10|
|2017-02-09|
|2017-02-08|
|2017-02-07|
....
```

Thanks

Comment: All days of a year or only the days between the first day of the year and  start_date (shouldn't it be end_date?)?

Comment: either way.... it's easier using the start_date, cos the end_date would be: `end_date=DATE_SUB('${start_date}',365)`....

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz can you help me on that?

Comment: Yes. However, I must say that computing a year as 365 days does not make a lot of sense business wise.

Comment: it's just an example... I will be happy to learn the better way! :) pls show me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set start_date=2017-02-14;

select  date_sub('${hiveconf:start_date}',i)
from    (select 1 as n) dummy lateral view posexplode(split(space(364),' ')) p as i,x
;
```

---

```
2017-02-14
2017-02-13
2017-02-12
2017-02-11
2017-02-10
.
.
.
2016-02-20
2016-02-19
2016-02-18
2016-02-17
2016-02-16
```

Comment: What's the best representation to one year ago from the start_date? I mean how would you do it in this case.?

Comment: How about 2016-02-15 (for 2017-02-14)? but this is for another post... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and an *older* start date for *testing* purposes:

```
start_date="2014-02-14"
days=$((($(date -u +%s) - $(date -ud $start_date +%s))/60/60/24))
(( day_end = 366 + days ))

while (( days < day_end  ));do
  date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$days days ago"
  (( days++ ))
done
```

**Result**

```
2014-02-14
2014-02-13
2014-02-12
2014-02-11
2014-02-10
2014-02-09
2014-02-08
2014-02-07
2014-02-06
2014-02-05
2014-02-04
...
...
...
2013-02-21
2013-02-20
2013-02-19
2013-02-18
2013-02-17
2013-02-16
2013-02-15
2013-02-14
```

Comment: i'm getting `date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`
how this date function works?

Comment: Must be an outdated version, mine: `date (GNU coreutils) 8.4`

Comment: yes! it's probably some issue on MAC OS date UNIX  as I could see here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1352105?tstart=0 and on others. Thanks again!

Comment: You can always install `gnu` *utils* via `brew`